# Maven test fails with UnsupportedClassVersion, but compilation passes

Tags: java, maven

I have very simple and dummy test of a class which uses pattern matching. To allow it I added compiler argument to my `pom.xml`:

```xml
...
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>--enable-preview</arg>
                        ...
...
```

And the compile works fine. But when I tried to run test, I got:

```
[ERROR] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.016 s <<< FAILURE! - in prefile.pref.ALineTest
[ERROR] testCreateEmpty1  Time elapsed: 0.016 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Preview features are not enabled for prefile/pref/ALine (class file version 61.65535). Try running with '--enable-preview'
    at prefile.pref.ALineTest.testCreateEmpty1(ALineTest.java:27)

[INFO] Running prefile.pref.APathTest
[INFO] Tests run: 16, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.015 s - in prefile.pref.APathTest
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Errors: 
[ERROR]   ALineTest.testCreateEmpty1:27 » UnsupportedClassVersion Preview features are n...
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Tests run: 26, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I tried to modify my `pom.xml`:

```xml
...
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>--enable-preview</arg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                    <source>17</source>
                    <source>17</source>
                    <testSource>17</testSource>
                    <testTarget>17</testTarget>
                    <testCompilerArguments>
                        <arg>--enable-preview</arg>
                    </testCompilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
...
```

I am not sure about versions, but `java -version` reports "17.0.1". Nothing helps. The compilation works, testing - does not. How to fix it?

PS. Also this strange message about a version `(class file version 61.65535)`. I tried to clean, compile and test again, the same error. I even tried OpenJDK 19, but the same error happens.

Comment: When using Preview features, you need to run it with the same Java version **and** add `--enable-preview` at runtime (for your tests) as well. Not just for the compiler. The "strange" class file version is because preview features are enabled.

Comment: @dan1st - hm, you are *right*, I removed `--enable-preview` also and it seems exactly this is the fix (or to add it in runtime as well).

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, I had old JUnit versions in my `pom.xml`, I changed them to the last version:

```xml
...
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.9.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
            <version>5.9.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.9.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
...
```

and everything works fine now (also I switched to the Java 19). And I removed `--enable-preview` - see the comment of @dan1st